# How to enable YouTube material design for my account?

Tags: youtube

Some accounts have a redesigned Material Design interface. How can I enable it **for a specific account**?

Comment: did you try Google yet? [This is from May last year](https://9to5google.com/2016/05/01/youtube-material-design-how-to/), but it could help. And [desktop](https://www.androidheadlines.com/2017/02/youtube-receives-material-redesign-and-dark-mode.html) this year.

Comment: I've already tried that. You need to sign out to do this and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

The new design is **not** tied to accounts, it's tied to cookies. You need to set either a specific parameter in the `PREF` cookie or set the `VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE` cookie to a specific value, but which value it is exactly changes all the time as YouTube is trying out new iterations.

If YouTube thinks your browser supports the new design, you can enable it on https://youtube.com/new.

Answer (score 3):

At present, using the following URL will take you to the new design [youtube.com/new](http://youtube.com/new).